# SQL index for regexp query

Tags: mysql

How can I improve performance for the following query?
What kind of index should I use?
I am using MySQL

```
SELECT b.title
FROM book b, person p, order o
WHERE b.bid = o.bid
AND o.pid = p.pid
AND b.title LIKE 'LOVE%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [how MySQL uses indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

In the case of your query:

- I would particularly recommend indexes on `b.bid`, `o.bid`, `o.pid` and `p.pid`, as these are being used to join tables. You may even want to consider using foreign keys.
- I would also consider an index on `b.title`, since you are using this in you where clause.

But if you want to know how changes are affecting your queries you should profile between each change to check how it has affected performance.

However, I would ask you to elaborate on your query - you're joining with tables `order` and `person`, but neither selecting from these tables nor using these in your where clauses. Are you just doing this to select books that have been ordered? In which case, why do you then join on `person`?

Comment: Actually my precise question is what kind of index to use on b.title? Considering that the query is using regexp for its search, should I use hash or B+tree in order to improve performance?